# how to set aspnet core Soap Response namespaces

Tags: c#, soap, namespaces

I had created a Server-side SOAP endpoint using Soap-Core (aspnet core).
But I need to set the namespaces for the response (the request is going great).

So, I have this Service Contract:

```
    public interface IToaProducerService
    {
        [OperationContract(Name = "send_message", Action = "agent_service/send_message")]
        [return: MessageParameter(Name = "send_message_response")]
        List<MessageResponseDTO> send_message(UserDTO user, MessagesDTO messages);
    }
```

With this, I have the follow response:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <send_messageResponse xmlns="urn:toatech:agent">
         <send_message_response>
            <MessageResponseDTO>
               <message_id>3138306</message_id>
               <status>sent</status>
            </MessageResponseDTO>
         </send_message_response>
      </send_messageResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

But I need the response looks like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:toatech:agent">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:send_message_response>
         <urn:message_response>
            <urn:message_id>3138306</urn:message_id>
            <urn:status>sent</urn:status>
         </urn:message_response>
      </urn:send_message_response>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I'm using the SoapSerializer.XmlSerializer in startup.cs
`app.UseSoapEndpoint<ToaProducerService>("/producer", new BasicHttpBinding(), SoapSerializer.XmlSerializer);`

So, I have some problems to resolve here:

1 - the  send_message_response and all children must have the "urn:" namespace

2 - I can't override the MessageResponseDTO name

MessageResponseDTO:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "message_response", Namespace = "urn:toatech:agent")]
    [XmlType(Namespace = "urn:toatech:agent")]
    public class MessageResponseDTO
    {
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "urn:toatech:agent")]
        public string message_id;

        [XmlElement(Namespace = "urn:toatech:agent")]
        public string status;

        [XmlElement(Namespace = "urn:toatech:agent")]
        public string description;
    }
```

For the request, I used the same approach (using XmlRoot with namespace and XmlElements too) and it works fine.